# What is the meaning of "encore" in this sentence?

Tags: sens, inversion

« Alors faites vite ! Si vous voulez épater tous ces bureaucrates de Washington, encore faut-il que vous soyez à Washington. »

"Still" or "again" doesn’t seem to fit exactly in this particular context. Also, why is "faut-il" inverted instead of the usual "il faut"?

Comment: *Encore* à sens restrictif. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/encore_faut-il; http://en.bab.la/dictionary/french-english/encore-faut-il-que; http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/encore+faut-il.html. C'est "encore" qui entraîne l'inversion du sujet :  [Inversion du sujet obligatoire après *encore* restrictif](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9opkVN9D2Afc.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans la phrase citée *encore* a un sens restrictif, c'est à dire qu'il introduit ici une condition pour que le fait se réalise.

La phrase citée équivaut à dire :

> Vous pourrez épater ces bureaucrates mais pour cela il faut que vous soyez à Washington.

Par ailleurs on fait l'inversion du sujet après *encore* à sens restrictif quand il est placé en début de proposition.

> Je vais lui offrir des chocolats à Nathalie pour son anniversaire, encore préfère-t-elle les roses.

(C'est une façon soutenu de dire « bien qu'elle préfère les roses »)

> Je vais lui offrir des chocolats, encore Nathalie préfère-t-elle les roses.

Dans cette dernière phrase, comme il y a un nom propre on laisse le nom propre devant le verbe et on met un pronom personnel pour faire l'inversion.

Mais :

> Si vous voulez épater tous ces bureaucrates de Washington, il faut encore que vous soyez à Washington.

Pas d'inversion parce que *encore* n'est plus au début de la proposition.

Encore n'est pas le seul adverbe concerné par cette inversion :

> Dans les propositions commençant par certains adverbes ou locutions marquant pour la plupart restriction ou opposition : *à peine, ainsi, aussi, au moins, difficilement, du moins, (et encore) en vain, vainement, rarement, peut-être, plutôt, à plus forte raison, aussi bien, sans doute,* si le sujet est un pronom personnel ou l'un des pronoms *ce, on,* il se place de préférence après le verbe, mais il peut aussi le précéder.
>   [...] *Toujours* (= en tout cas), *encore*, *mais encore* (= malgré cela, *tout au plus*, exigent l'inversion du sujet, si celui-ci est un pronom personnel ou l'un des pronoms *ce, on*. [Grevisse, deuxième édition, § 187]

---

In the phrase *encore faut-il* *encore* has a restrictive sense, it introduces a condition for the action to come true.  When *encore* has a restrictive sense and is at the beginning of the sentence then the subject is placed after the verb.

*Encore faut-il* is usually rendered by "however". ("..however you'll have to be in Washington", "...however she prefers roses".

Comment: Could you please insert the links you gave in a comment directly in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

To better understand this, you can just change the order of the words :

> Alors faites vite ! Si vous voulez épater tous ces bureaucrates de Washington, **il faut encore** que vous soyez à Washington.
>   Then be quick ! If you want to impress all those bureaucrats of Washington, you still need to be in Washington.

Which means something like : you still/at least need to do it, in other words, it's not done yet, don't take it for granted.
When someone says that, it's often in order to remind you that, before your great objective gets accomplished, you have to at least aim for that necessary something - here, to be in Washington.

As for the inversion of "encore faut-il", I will just copy Laure's link : [Inversion du sujet obligatoire après *encore* restrictif](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_i&page=9opkVN9D2Afc.html).